# Given an array of integers, how can I assign the ints to two different arrays that have a capacity?

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

You're given a list of integers, you must add the integers to one of two lists, each of these lists has the same capacity that the sum of ints inside the list must be under.

This is just a rough description of the problem I'm looking to solve, I am trying to apply the same logic to an advanced project. I tried doing a greedy approach but this is a dynamic programming problem so I need a better solution for edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bin packing problem with 2 bins, which in the worst case, is equivalent to a subset sum problem.

Let S be the sum of your array A, and C the capacity of each of the two sublists. Clearly if S > 2C there can be no solution. Otherwise, S ≤ 2C and you need to find a subsequence of A whose sum is between S-C and C, so that the complement has sum at most C.

This is a classical subset sum problem that you can solve with the standard dynamic programming algorithm that you can find on Wikipedia or any number of other places.

Comment: Seems like this is the right direction, thank you mate. Just to verify this problem is NP-hard typically, right?

Comment: Like the subset sum problem on integers, the problem you described is pseudo-polynomial. It's solvable in O(C + N) time and O(C) space, where C is the bin capacity and N is the length of the array A.